# Não seria o caso de reavaliar os critérios de fechar perguntas?

Tags: debate, perguntas, fechamento

Há uns 7 anos atrás eu era assíduo do SOpt e o site fluía muito bem, mas hoje em dia, apesar de eu não ser mais um assíduo, vez em quando eu entro e vejo que (vou chutar por baixo) 90% das perguntas estão fechadas, a maioria não por votos, mas por moderadores. Olhei apenas nas 2 primeiras páginas, onde eu setei pra ver 50 perguntas por páginas.

No SO gringo eu fiz a mesma coisa a não vi sequer uma pergunta fechada nas 2 primeiras páginas, 0%. Eu sei que esse tema já está pacificado comparando o SOpt com SO gringo, mas não vim aqui comparar os dois sites.

A minha questão era se não seria legal que os moderadores fossem mais tolerantes, ou seja, alargassem o alcance de tolerância em perguntas ruins em vez de fechá-las sumariamente. É verdade que muitas das perguntas fechadas (senão a totalidade delas) realmente são péssimas, mas não seria a hora de aumentar o nível de tolerância para que o site voltasse a fluir melhor no sentido das pessoas quererem frequentar, perguntar, responder etc.?

A impressão que dá é que o site está emperrado, tipo uma cidade fantasma. Acho que teria que dar uma maior tolerância porque a maioria dos usuários novos que se cadastram aqui são iniciantes em programação e a maioria não sabem nem se expressar. Dificilmente um programador experiente irá fazer uma pergunta. Programadores experientes frequentadores do site estão lá mais pra responder perguntas.

Comment: Eu estive olhando a página de perguntas do SO e no intervalo de uma hora entre a publicação da sua pergunta aqui e o momento em estou lendo, nessa madrugada de domingo entraram no SO 97 perguntas sendo até o momento 3 foram fechadas, ao olhar por cima as salas de chat do SO não vi a presença de moderadores ou seja lá no SO ingresso de perguntas é muito maior que o nosso dificultando a curadoria e moderação de conteúdo de baixa qualidade. Se olhar o META SO na tag [closed-questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/closed-questions) a reclamação sobre fechamentos é constante.

Comment: Eu concordo que dificilmente um programador experiente irá fazer uma pergunta e que programadores experientes frequentadores do site estão lá mais pra responder perguntas. Sim, más há um fenômeno que ocorre aqui e não ocorre lá, os usuários aqui estão reiteradamente fazendo perguntas duplicas, não há o aparecimento de questões novas. São feitas sempre a mesmas questões cujo a solução poderia ser encontrada ao se fazer uma consulta no acervo do site. Uma ou outra duplicata escapam, as respostas nessas duplicatas em geral tendem a absurdos que poderiam serem evitados se houvesse consulta prévia.

Comment: Outra coisa que esqueci de mencionar, diferente daqui o SO possui o programa [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429606/staging-ground-is-coming-back-and-moving-out-of-beta?cb=1) que é uma área reservada onde os novos usuários podem obter ajuda e feedback de revisores experientes no Stack Overflow antes de suas perguntas entrarem no site principal. Esse programa foi iniciado em 2022 e trás resultados positivos na introdução de novos usuários na cultura da plataforma.

Comment: Outra ferramenta que também está mostrando algum resultado e não dispomos é a [pesquisa orientada por IA](https://stackoverflow.com/ai/search) onde antes do usuário criar uma pergunta a IA busca dentro do acervo do site possíveis soluções já encontradas.